# Parse only one level of json

Tags: python, json

I have the following string:

```
'{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": ["a","b", 3],
    "key3": {"foo": 27, "bar": [1, 2, 3]}
}'
```

I want to parse only one level so result should be a one level dictionary with key, and value should be just a string(don't need to parse it)

For given string it should return following dictionary:

```
{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "['a','b', 3]",
    "key3": "{'foo': 27, 'bar': [1, 2, 3]}"
}
```

Is there a fast way to do it? Without parsing whole string to json and convert all values back to strings.

Comment: you have to parse the whole json string, and grab the string parts.. it's doable, but I doubt it's worth the effort. Is the performance really critical?

Comment: yes it should be part of performance critical code

Comment: Also if I directly converts each value to str I will receive nasty u prefixes for strings:  
`foo = json.loads('{"key1": "val1", "key2": ["a","b", 3], "key3": {"foo": 27, "bar": [1, 2, 3]}}')`  
`dict([(k, str(v)) for k,v in foo.iteritems()])`  
will give me:  
`{u'key1': 'val1',  
 u'key2': "[u'a', u'b', 3]",  
 u'key3': "{u'foo': 27, u'bar': [1, 2, 3]}"`

Comment: I doubt you can do this with the default JSON module, the grammar of the language needs to be altered to give the functionality you desire -- or in other words, if you want this result you have to parse a different language; your desired input/output is not part of the language that JSON represents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can solve this using regex, it is working for me:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"\s*:\s*(".*"|\[.*\]|\{.*\})')    
dict(re.findall(pattern, json_string))
```

But I dont know if this is faster, you need try using your data.

[EDIT]

Yes, it is faster. I tried the scripts below and the regex version is 5 times faster.

using json module:

```
import json

val='''
{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": ["a","b", 3],
    "key3": {"foo": 27, "bar": [1, 2, 3]}
}
'''

for n in range(100000):
    dict((k,json.dumps(v)) for k,v in json.loads(val).items())
```

using regex:

```
import re

val='''{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": ["a","b", 3],
    "key3": {"foo": 27, "bar": [1, 2, 3]}
}'''

pattern = re.compile('"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"\s*:\s*(".*"|\[.*\]|\{.*\})')    
for n in range(100000):
    dict(re.findall(pattern, val))
```

Comment: This does not match all the valid json values, I have used this regex `'"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"\s*:\s*(".*"|\[.*\]|\{.*\}|-?(\d+(\.\d+)?e?\d*)|true|false|null)'` https://regex101.com/r/F3Tqfj/1

Answer (score 3):

Hardly an answer, but I only see two possibilities:

1. Load the full JSON and dump back the values, which you have ruled out in your question
2. Modify the content by wrapping the values in quotes, so that the JSON load yields string values

To be honest, I think there is no such thing as '*performance critical* JSON parsing code', it just sounds wrong, so I'd go with the first option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now if it's really what you need, but try

```
>>> import json
>>> val = """
... {
... "key1": "val1",
... "key2": ["a","b", 3],
... "key3": {"foo": 27, "bar": [1, 2, 3]}
... }
... """
>>> dict((k,json.dumps(v)) for k,v in json.loads(val).items())
{u'key3': '{"foo": 27, "bar": [1, 2, 3]}', u'key2': '["a", "b", 3]', u'key1': '"val1"'}
```

It's little bit tricky, cause you load to JSON full object and than just dump back values in dictionary.

Comment: "Without parsing whole string to json and convert all values back to strings."